# Modify element based on given array in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am looking for a way to change element content to "Yes" based on productID in a given array/list.

Status can be Yes/No (or unset).

**Source XML:**

```
<xml>
<product>
<productId>111111</productId>
<available>No</available>
</product>
<product>
<productId>888888</productId>
<available>No</available>
</product>
<product>
<productId>666666</productId>
<available>No</available>
</product>
<product>
<productId>99999</productId>
<available>Yes</available>
</product>
<product>
<productId>333333</productId>
<available>Yes</available>
</product>
</xml>
```

Here is a sample array with productID's:

```
111111,666666,99999
```

I want to achieve that available element for these productID's are always set to "Yes". Products which are not in the list should be not changed in the output.

**Example output:**

```
<xml>
<product>
<productId>111111</productId>
<available>Yes</available>
</product>
<product>
<productId>888888</productId>
<available>No</available>
</product>
<product>
<productId>666666</productId>
<available>Yes</available>
</product>
<product>
<productId>99999</productId>
<available>Yes</available>
</product>
<product>
<productId>333333</productId>
<available>Yes</available>
</product>
</xml>
```

Bonus question: suggestions for manipulating the array with bash/php are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future, here is the XSLT 2.0 version by @MartinHonnen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

     <!-- .test: 111111,888888,99999,666666 -->
    <xsl:variable name="available" select="unparsed-text('.test')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="ids" select="for $t in tokenize($available, ',') return normalize-space($t)"/>
        <xsl:template match="product[productId = $ids]/available">
        <available>Yes</available>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="available" select="'111111,666666,99999'" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product/available">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test ="contains( concat(',',$available, ','),
                                            concat(',',../productId, ',') )">
                    <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The two `concat` are not imperative, but good practice to avoid get a falls trues because of matching a shorter id in a longer one.
Which will generate this outtput:

```
<xml>
    <product>
        <productId>111111</productId>
        <available>yes</available>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productId>888888</productId>
        <available>No</available>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productId>666666</productId>
        <available>yes</available>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productId>99999</productId>
        <available>yes</available>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productId>333333</productId>
        <available>Yes</available>
    </product>
</xml>
```

Changing the param available depend on your xslt  processor. For example xsltproc supports stringparam:

```
--stringparam name value : pass a (parameter, UTF8 string value) pair
```

Therefor you can call it e.g.:

```
 xsltproc --stringparam available "888888" test.xsl in.xml
```

Comment: Super, thank you. I think you missed a comma between the two concat function. Without comma I get error on xsltransform.net, with comma it works.

Comment: I would like to read arrays from an external file (for easier manipulating with the file), so I am trying to use `<xsl:param name="available" select="unparsed-text('.test')" />`, in `.test` I have: `111111,888888,99999,666666`. Do you have any idea why it fails? The 666666 does not get modified. I wanted to show you on xsltransform.net, but it is currently not working.

Comment: To red form an external file you can use `<xsl:variable name="available select="document(`.test.xml') />` But than you need to provide your data as xml. unparsed-text should be work if your xslt processor support **xslt 2.0**. You need to change to `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" />`. and use variable instead of param.

Comment: Where do you expect xsltransform.net to read the `unparsed-text('.test')` from? You are not able to upload local files there. If you install an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 on your system then you can of course use `unparsed-text('.test')` to read in a local file. As for the whole code, if you really can use XSLT 2.0, then the whole approach becomes much easier as you can simply use `<xsl:variable name="ids" select="tokenize($available, ',')"/><xsl:template match="product[productId = $ids]/available"><available>Yes</available></xsl:template>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hey, I am running my own copy of xsltransform.net: https://github.com/joepjoosten/XSL-tester. :) Thanks for the tokenize version, however it is still not working, but I figured out: `111111,888888,99999,666666` -> not working. If I add comma after last item (666666), it is working. Is there any way to make it work without last comma?

Comment: What does the text file contain after the last digit, any white space or a linefeed or carriage return? In that case you need e.g. `<xsl:variable name="ids" select="for $t in tokenize($available, ',') return normalize-space($t)"/>` or some replace to chop off the trailing characters.